# I'm not able to flag after using all my close votes

Tags: support, flagging, vote-to-close

I've used up my **close** votes for the day, so I am trying to **flag** duplicates instead. I can no longer flag a duplicate for moderator attention. I have 39 flags remaining, this should work. (I'm attempting to flag [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/194548/12864) as a dupe of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/3815/12864), but it happens with multiple questions)

I get as far as the first dialog after clicking 'flag' after which the bug occurs.

**Normal**: (click 'flag', 'flag question' message on greyed-out button at bottom right)

[image: First flag question dialogue]

**Bug**: (message on button switches to 'Vote to close', even though I am attempting to flag and out of votes)

[image: second flag dialogue exhibiting bug]

I can click on the 'exact duplicate' radio button at this point, and even choose or paste in the link, but cannot flag the question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149693/should-moderator-flags-be-available-to-close-an-older-question-for-users-who-alr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find the MSO Q&A on this, but I'm 99% sure that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The system is designed for Stack Overflow, and they design it so that if you're out of the "lay man" votes, you need to just let it be. This is a problem on small-medium sites like ours.

Anyway, just flag it using this "It needs moderator attention > Other", and explain. I used to do that, and I know of many other prominent users of the site who also do that.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it now. I think I found the [Q&A here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113730), and it's because flagging dupes **automatically** gets converted to a close vote if you have the privilege. Good to know.

Answer (score 3):

After you get to the 3000 rep, your flag in the category **it doesn't belong here or it's a duplicate**  becomes a close vote. If you select anything from that category such as

- **exact duplicate**
- **off topic**
- **not constructive**
- **not a real question**
- **too localized**

That will be counted as a close vote. They do not flag or alarm the moderator. Since you consumed all the close votes for the day, you can't flag question on that category.

And yes, you can still flag a question using other types of flag, such as spam and offensive.